# Table with two cells with CSS?

Tags: css, html-table

I want to get this result, but with no tables (with pure CSS):

[image]

With tables I can do something like this with one 'tr' and two 'td' tags, but how to do it without tables?

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5r33zey4/)

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <div id="inputs">
          <p>Add some value:</p>
          <input type="text"/>
          <br/>
          <input type="button" title="Press Ok" value="Ok"/>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="choices">
            <ul>
              <li>some choice</li>
              <li>some choice</li>
              <li>some choice</li>
              <li>some choice</li>
              <li>some choice</li>
              <li>some choice</li>
              <li>some choice</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: There are so many ways to achieve this, you should specify the oldest browser you need to support to get the best answer

Comment: Thank You all very much guys for great answers!

Comment: your welcome. :) :) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ditch the table markup and use CSS:

```
#inputs, #choices {
  display:table-cell
}
```

```css
#inputs, #choices {
  display:table-cell
}
```

```html
<div id="inputs">
  <p>Add some value:</p>
  <input type="text" />
  <br/>
  <input type="button" title="Press Ok" value="Ok" />
</div>

<div id="choices">
  <ul>
    <li>some choice</li>
    <li>some choice</li>
    <li>some choice</li>
    <li>some choice</li>
    <li>some choice</li>
    <li>some choice</li>
    <li>some choice</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Flexbox` and set `align-items: center` on flex container.

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div id="inputs">
    <p>Add some value:</p>
    <input type="text" />
    <br/>
    <input type="button" title="Press Ok" value="Ok" />
  </div>
  <div id="choices">
    <ul>
      <li>some choice</li>
      <li>some choice</li>
      <li>some choice</li>
      <li>some choice</li>
      <li>some choice</li>
      <li>some choice</li>
      <li>some choice</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems to me you're answering how to vertically center elements, even though that wasn't part of the question whatsoever.

Comment: Change `align-items: center;` to `align-items: flex-start;` to get the result in the OP's reference image.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `float:left`

```css
#left{
  float:left;
}
#right{
  float:left;
  left:300px;
}
```

```html
   <div id="left"
        <div id="inputs">
          <p>Add some value:</p>
          <input type="text"/>
          <br/>
          <input type="button" title="Press Ok" value="Ok"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="right"
        <div id="choices">
            <ul>
              <li>some choice</li>
              <li>some choice</li>
              <li>some choice</li>
              <li>some choice</li>
              <li>some choice</li>
              <li>some choice</li>
              <li>some choice</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `inline-block` display for the most simple and native way to solve this:

```css
.content > div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div id="inputs">
    <p>Add some value:</p>
    <input type="text" />
    <br/>
    <input type="button" title="Press Ok" value="Ok" />
  </div>
  <div id="choices">
    <ul>
      <li>some choice</li>
      <li>some choice</li>
      <li>some choice</li>
      <li>some choice</li>
      <li>some choice</li>
      <li>some choice</li>
      <li>some choice</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

While all three of the other answers work, there's no reason to use table display (seeing as you're trying to avoid tables in the first place) or flexbox (while it works great, there's the [compatibility issue](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)). Floats share none of those disadvantages, however come with the requirement to clear them.